# MongoDB Rolling Index Build

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to optimize application performance while building indexes in production, we usually build 2 or 3 indexes every month, but even with brackground builds, it causes performance issues, we have a very large sharded dataset.

MongoDB documentation recommends using a rolling index build (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/)

However this process seems very tedious and manual, is there a tool/script to automate this out there? Anyone has any experience with rolling indexes via OpsManager or manually?

I want to migrate to Rolling Indexes via OpsManager but wanted to know about other people's experience and issues.

Comment: Atlas apparently [offers automated rolling index builds](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/indexes/). I cannot quite figure out where or whether this is exposed through ops manager/cloud manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Ops Manager's Data Explorer to create an index, you can build with rolling build.